# no suitable constructor exists to convert from void to std:thread

Tags: c++, multithreading

I am messing around with threads for the first time and i want to make this into a thread but seem to be doing something wrong.

```
void FloodFill(CDIB32* scr, int x, int y)

{

 scr ->GetRGB(x,y, (byte) r,(byte) g,(byte)b);
 if (r == 255 && g == 0 && b == 0)
     return;

 if (!(r == 255 && g == 255 && b == 255))
    return;

 scr ->SetRGB(x, y,(byte)255,(byte) 0,(byte) 0);

    FloodFill(&m_screenDib, x+1, y);
    FloodFill(&m_screenDib, x-1, y);
    FloodFill(&m_screenDib, x, y+1);
    FloodFill(&m_screenDib, x, y-1);
    FloodFill(&m_screenDib, x+1, y+1);
    FloodFill(&m_screenDib, x+1, y-1);
    FloodFill(&m_screenDib, x-1, y+1);
    FloodFill(&m_screenDib, x-1, y-1);
    return;

}


void DoIt()

{

if (!m_done)
{
    Reset();

    for (int i = 0; i < REZ * REZ; ++i)
    {
        CPoint mid;
        GetBlobMidPoint(i, mid);

        xpos = mid.x;
        ypos = mid.y;

        FloodFill(&m_screenDib, xpos, ypos);
        std::thread floodfill([this, xpos, ypos] { FloodFill(&m_screenDib, xpos, ypos); });

    ::PostMessage(g_hWnd, FLOOD_FINISHED, NULL, NULL);

    m_done = true;
    }
}
```

}

Floodfill is a simple floodfill algorithm i get the error

Error   1   error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'void' to 'std::thread'

Comment: [http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/thread](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/thread) for a reference on the `std::thread` constructor including code examples.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're *calling* the function `FloodFill` instead of passing it to the thread. Do this instead:

```
std::thread floodfill(&FloodFill, &m_screenDib, xpos, ypos);
```

---

If your standard library doesn't correctly implement this part of the standard, you might be able to get around it with a function object:

```
std::thread floodfill([this, xpos, ypos] { FloodFill(&m_screenDib, xpos, ypos); });
```

The above assumes the code in the question is actually inside a non-static member function of a class which has a member `m_screenDib`. If that's not the case, the lambda would have to be adjusted accordingly.

Now that it's been clarified all the variables involved are global, there's no need to capture them. Just do this:

```
std::thread floodfill([] { FloodFill(&m_screenDib, xpos, ypos); });
```

Comment: If i do that the error changes to 
Error 1 error C2661: 'std::thread::thread' : no overloaded function takes 4 arguments

Comment: @ppverbatim Which compiler (VS version) are you using? It seems it's not standard conformant in this.

Comment: I am using VS Express 2012 for windows desktop

Comment: @ppverbatim Added a potential workaround; not sure how well VS2012 implements `std::thread`, but it might help.

Comment: It seems VS is not swallowing this at all:

Error 1 error C3482: 'this' can only be used as a lambda capture within a non-static member function 

Error 2 error C3480: 'xpos': a lambda capture variable must be from an enclosing function scope 

Error 3 error C3480: 'ypos': a lambda capture variable must be from an enclosing function scope 

Error 4 error C1903: unable to recover from previous error(s); stopping compilation

Comment: @ppverbatim You didn't provide enough context in your question, so I made the best guess I could. I assumed the code was inside a non-static member function, because of the `m_` prefix on `screenDib`. The idea is to create a lambda that will do the call for you and capture all it needs for it. You can do that yourself, I assume.

Comment: I added the entire function i am looking at lambda now to see if i can work that out.

Comment: @ppverbatim Where does `m_done` and (most importantly) `m_screenDib` come from? Are these just incredibly badly named global variables? And where is `xpos` and `ypos` declared?

Comment: They are all declared at the top 
CDIB32 m_screenDib;
int xpos, ypos;
bool m_done;

I guess you could say they are badly named global variables they seemed to make sense at the time.

Comment: @ppverbatim How can a non-member variable starting with `m_` make sense ever? But anyway, I'll amend the answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help this seems to work. Now i just need to catch my infinite loop it created and i'm done thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Your code tries to initialise a thread with the result of calling a function, which makes no sense.

Presumably, you want the thread to call that function. You need to pass a function pointer (or function object) as the first constructor argument, followed by whatever arguments should be passed to it:

```
std::thread floodfill(FloodFill, &m_screenDib, xpos, ypos);
std::thread floodfill([=]{FloodFill(&m_screenDib, xpos, ypos);});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `(FloodFill(&m_screenDib, xpos, ypos)` is an actual  function call. You're trying to initialize the thread with the **results** of the function call.

Instead, pass the function and its arguments separately to the thread: 
`std::thread floodfill { &FloodFill, &m_screenDib, xpos, ypos };`

Note that many GUI technologies do not support threads.